# How to get some string from database?

Tags: java, android, database, string

I need to using only type *1*, if I have many items on database.
How I can get name by type =1 from the database?

For example Database:

```
NAME                      TYPE    QTY    UNITPRICE    AMT
Chrome Polish (12oz)        0      3         35       105
ice less                    1      1          0         0
Cleaner Wax paste (12oz)    0      1       1200      1200
Pure Brazliain paste        0      1          0        80
Car Wash (16oz)             1      1          0         0
Carnaubar Wash&Wax(64oz)    0      1       2350      2350
```

Comment: `select NAME from <table_name> where TYPE='1';`

Comment: You'll be smart to rethink those table and column names.   Make them a bit more descriptive and less likely to be SQL keywords (TYPE might be a problem).

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT NAME FROM YOURTABLE WHERE TYPE=1
```

You can apply above query based on table format which you have provided in your question.(I have included a copy below)

```
NAME                      TYPE    QTY    UNITPRICE    AMT
Chrome Polish (12oz)        0      3         35       105
ice less                    1      1          0         0
Cleaner Wax paste (12oz)    0      1       1200      1200
```